# Need a swipe plugin for my Phonegap project

Tags: html, cordova, swipeview

i have tried lot of swipe plugins in my phonegap project, but my form elements are not working in these plugins.
can you suggest a better plugin for my project?

This is the screen what i need.

[image]

thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you tried idangerous swiper? http://www.idangero.us/sliders/swiper/

Comment: @ mvp, Yup i am also tried this. this is the question  asked when i faced issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20143428/form-elements-not-working-in-phonegap-with-idangerous-swiper-plugin

Comment: if u r sharing jsfiddle of your code, people can answer you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your plugin:
https://github.com/linslin/pagingSlider

Features:

- slide to pages with touch swipes
- auto switch to pages by clicking menu item
- animated mobile pagebrowser
- integrated touch events with QuoJS

[image]

Comment: Thanks lin, for share your knowledge.

Comment: Hi, I tried this plugin however I m getting the below error .VM17279:4 Uncaught TypeError: _listenTouches is not a function
    at <anonymous>:4:14145
    at Array.e.fn.ready (<anonymous>:4:11320)
    at <anonymous>:4:14121
    at <anonymous>:4:18223
    at b (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:866)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:2905)
    at Object.dataFilter (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:80720)
    at jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79185
    at l (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:79587)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.6.0.min.js:2:82355)